# create the admin system for my program via ADT linkedlist

Tags: c++

```
class Attraction {
    protected:
        int id;
        string name;
        int typeID;

    public:
        Attraction(int id, string name, int typeID):id(id),name(name),typeID(typeID){};

        // getters and setters
        int getId(){return id;}
        void setId(){this->id=id;}
        string getName(){return name;}
        void setName(string name){this->name=name;}
        int getTypeID(){return typeID;}
        void setTypeID(){this->typeID=typeID;}


        virtual void display()=0;//abstract class

};
// City object
class City {
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& ,City &);
        private:
        int id;
        string name;

        // vector might changed to your own ADT in milestone 2, since STL only acceptable in milestone 1
        vector<City*> directFlight; // adjacent connected cities
        LinkedList<Attraction*> attractions; // contained attractions
        public:
        City(int id, string name):id(id),name(name){};

        // getters and setters
        int getId(){return id;}
        void setId(int id){this->id=id;}
        string getName(){return name;}
        void setName(){this->name=name;}
        void addAttraction(int pos,Attraction*attraction)
        {
            attractions.insert(pos,attraction);
        }
        //bool isConnected(int cityID); // Check city is directly connected
        /*Attraction* getAttractions(int index)
        {
            return this->attractions[index];
        }*/


};
```

Use an ADT stack to implement a depth-first search to answer whether city A and city B are connected by flights, either directly or indirectly. 
- To store the flight map of cities, implement an adjacency matrix using a dynamic 2D array. 
can anyone give me an suggestion how to use the ADT stack to implement a DFS?
i dont understand this part,anyone can guide me?
from my attraction class and City class and Attraction on top,how to implement this two things?

Comment: Take a look at the stack type to get an overview of the interface, that should give you an idea how to use it implementing a DFS.

Comment: BTW: The title of your question plainly sucks. What does it and the text below have to do with each other? How is the code you post relevant? I believe you yourself are confused, because you try to solve too many problems at once in the context of a bigger program. Don't do that, divide and conquer instead!